# Sphinx searchd error: Query failed: expected searchd protocol version 1+, got version '0'

Tags: linux, search, sphinx

I've recently installed Sphinx search on an EC2 instance running CentOS.  Using search from the command line works fine and I've created a valid index of documents.  When I try to access the php api through the searchd daemon, however, I get the following error:

```
Query failed: expected searchd protocol version 1+, got version '0'
```

Here is the searchd config info from sphinx.conf:

```
searchd
{
    listen          = /var/run/searchd.sock
    log             = /usr/local/sphinx/var/log/searchd.log
    query_log       = /usr/local/sphinx/var/log/query.log
    read_timeout    = 5
    max_children    = 30
    pid_file        = /usr/local/sphinx/var/log/searchd.pid
    max_matches     = 1000
    seamless_rotate = 1
    preopen_indexes = 1
    unlink_old      = 1
    workers         = threads # for RT to work
}
```

I cannot resolve this.  Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT 1: I have started the searchd daemon.

Answer (score 1):

There is missmatch with API and searchd versions. It could be better to use same API as searchd.

Comment: I'm using the included versions of both from the generally recommended release, 2.0.1-beta. How could I verify this problem and then find the correct versions to use together?

Comment: It could be 2 daemons running and you connects to oldest one. Could you issue "ps aufx | grep searchd" to make sure that its one daemon alive?

Answer (score 0):

The version of you PHP api is lower than searchd.
Just try the same client api as searchd.

Answer (score 0):

It's a performance issue most probably.
When searchd is unable to respond to too many requests you will get that error.